# How to get process detailed infos in android

Tags: java, android, process

I'm wondering if it is possible to get detailed process info in android like:
-ppid
-gid
-uname
-gname
-runtime
-priority

I know how to get process info in RunningAppProcessInfo class but it not contains those fields above.

Tnx